Can you process push notification content if the end user did not tap on it?
If a regular (not silent) push notification is sent to an app, and a user is not acting on it in any way, will the app "know" about it? Or it has to be silent push?

Have a look at the Notification Extension. You can have a short time to do minimal processing. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

"will the app "know" about it".
If you implement a notification service extension, then when the push is sent to the app it can be intercepted by the notification extension.
Note that the push will be delivered to the extension and not to the app, the extension and the app are separate entities. The extension cannot launch the app or call code in the app etc.
However the extension itself can perform various functionality, run code etc. on behalf of the app.
The app and the extension can share files/databases/user preferences etc. So the extension could, for example save the content of the push payload to a database, then next time the app runs it could examine the database and thus know that a push was received and extract the data saved by the extension.

The extension can also make network calls so possibly log to a back end that the notification has been received
